# What to do if a Company terminates your contract before 1 week of joining date?

Tags: employment, breach-of-contract, malaysia

Working in Malaysia I got a job offer from one of the famous MNCs 1 month ago under another Company's payroll. I got the offer letter and all the documentation is complete. I resigned from my current Company and my EP is canceled too. The documents for new EP has already been submitted by the new Company.

1 week before the joining date, I was informed that the project is canceled. Now I am stranded. Can I sue the Company?

Comment: What does the contract say about contingencies such as the project being cancelled? Does the contract guarantee employment for any particular period?

Comment: Yes, they guaranteed employment for at least 6 months.

Comment: Not sure what an "EP" is in this context.

Answer (score 3):

If you had a contract guaranteeing employment for six months and it was cancelled without cause, you could sue the new employer for breach of contract for six months of wages and relocation/loss of benefit damages, less any mitigation of damages you could accomplish by finding alternative employment.